# Mongo DB - Robomongo Json output invalid

Tags: json, mongodb, validation, lint, robo3t

Connected Robomongo to a mongodb database and once i write a query in the shell and try to copypaste the output into a text editor, then save it as a Json. Power BI, as well as Json lint will tell me that's an invalid file.

Any suggestions?